# Unable to set default custom settings

Tags: apex, trigger, customsetting

I have written an apex class which makes a callout to an external API, and the endpoints need to be different for the sandbox and production.

I need functionality like environmental variables so the code can remain unchanged and the variables can be different in production.

I came across custom settings which looks fine for this purpose but after I create the custom setting, create my desired fields, when I put in organization default values it hangs and times out after a few minutes saying "Time limit exceeded: Your request exceeded the time limit for processing.".

I've tried waiting an hour or so and seeing if it resolves itself but I always get this result, and no values are inserted.

- **Why is this happening?**
- and **are there any alternatives to custom settings for this purpose?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this through the use of named credentials:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=named_credentials_about.htm&type=5

...A named credential specifies the URL of a callout endpoint and its required authentication parameters in one definition. To simplify the setup of authenticated callouts, specify a named credential as the callout endpoint...

Comment: perfect, exactly what I was looking for